# How do I update an Android authenticator module (AbstractAccountAuthenticator)?

Tags: android, authentication

I have an authenticator module (implements [AbstractAccountAuthenticator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AbstractAccountAuthenticator.html)) which my apps use for signing in, and many users have more than one of my apps installed. I am aware that the first app to be installed has its authenticator re-used for all future installs.

However, I am releasing an app update which requires an updated version of my authenticator. How can I get the installed authenticator to update to the new code?

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question? I'd be interested to find out what you did. Cheers!

Comment: @luuts Nope. AFAIK, it's just the way that is. I have to make sure it works both ways (doesn't break old versions, and works with new versions). I'm moving away from using them in general.

Comment: Ah well, thanks @schwegs

Comment: This is so dumb of Google, in my humble opinion. First of all it is undocumented, and it defies pure common sense, preventing developers from updating the logic (or appearance) of their own authentication flow by just updating one of the applications.

Answer (score 0):

I have opened an issue in the Android Issue Tracker:
https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/71788024

I'm not very confident this is going to be looked at anytime soon. I do continue to rely on `AccountManager` for my applications, but the fact that its API hasn't been updated in ages makes me think that Google isn't going to invest much on it (in favour of Smart Lock and the Credentials API in the Play Services).